# Property/method definition

Tags: c#

```
public class PaginationHelper<T> : IPagination<T>
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Items { get; set; }
    public IList<T> PaginationItems => AsPagination();
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int FirstItem => (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize + 1;

    public int LastItem => FirstItem + PageSize - 1;

    public int TotalPages
    {
        get
        {
            var result = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)TotalItems / PageSize);
            return result == 0 ? 1 : result;
        }
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage => PageNumber > 1;

    public bool HasNextPage => PageNumber < TotalPages;

    public List<T> AsPagination()
    {
        var numberToSkip = (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize;
        var results = Items.Skip(numberToSkip).Take(PageSize).ToList();
        return results;
    }
}

public class Paginator<T>
{
    public List<T> PaginationItems { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
}
```

My friend gave me this code, and I can't compile. When define a property/method in C#, is it possible to use in this way?
public int FirstItem => (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize + 1; Is it right syntax??

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? That syntax was introduced in VS 2015

Comment: could you give us the specific error? or does it just say syntax error... if so, on what line?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm using VS 2013...

Comment: @nstraub I think this is because I use VS 2013

Comment: @nstraub Compiler says "Error 6 ; expected" and "Error 7 Invalid token '-' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Comment: @RegencySoftware No, but I think I get it. This's a new C# syntax

Comment: yeah that would be the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That syntax; formally known as an **expression-bodied member** was introduced in C# 6 and the VS 2015 C# compiler.

Earlier versions of Visual Studio will not compile it; you'll have to refactor to C# 5 compliant code:

```
public int FirstItem { get { return (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize + 1; } }
```

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks so much.